# Help me on uitableview section

Tags: uitableview, ios4

I have uitableview with 3 sections. for the second section i want to have line above it and below to it.i mean like below..how can i achive it..

---

```
                Section 2
```

---

Thanks for nay help

Comment: Do you mean whole section 2 with header, footer & cells or only its header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use seperaterField bellow and above the section2 manager